# Dependent projects and obfuscation

Tags: java, android, eclipse, obfuscation

I'm working on Android code that exists partly in a library project and partly in an app project; the app depends on the library.  But the library is obfuscated, so instead of

```
import com.mycompany.mylibrary.MyClass
```

I have

```
import myobfuscatedlib.MyClass
```

This works fine in production, but I am trying to debug, and I would like to step into the library's methods; I would also like to be able to edit the library classes, then run the app and see my changes.  At present the jar that the library file creates is in the app's build path; if I replace the jar with a project reference, all my imports are invalidated.  How can I configure my projects to debug the unobfuscated code while obfuscating for the production build?

Comment: You should use nonobfuscated library for development. Just replace obfuscate jar file with library sources or full jar.

Comment: @Eugen, you say "just replace" the jar, but my app source files all make reference to the classes by name (including full path, of course), and I would prefer not to have to change every import of every source file in my app.  Do you know any way to do that?

Comment: Sorry I didn't read your post accurately! But I don't see any value to use obfuscated library. I wouldn't obfuscate library at all. And for the production I would obfuscate project with library together. I'm afraid what you're asking isn't possible with current tools right now.

Comment: Thanks, @Eugen, I'm afraid I don't have a choice; our customer requires us to obfuscate the library, and the project is a test app that uses the library.  I'm afraid you're right about what's currently possible - but I hope you're wrong.

Comment: you don't break requirement about obfuscation if you do it in the release build. Again use nonobfuscated versions in development and obfuscate them both in production.